# firefox extension help

Tags: firefox

I am developing a firefox extension which needs to add some html on the page it runs.

This element I will be writing needs to be decorated with css and also load some images.

I have both the css file and the images in the plugin, but I do not know how to reference them.

Do I need to insert the css file to the page I want to modify?

In the css file how can I reference the images that are in the extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use chrome notation:

Check here:

http://www.ar-ent.net/dar/arlib32/out/html/man/xul/textimage.html

Comment: Right. But how do you load the css in the page? Do I have to or if I load it into my extension's xul file it will handle the elements on the page

Comment: Yolu can do it using the overlay configuration in your extension settings, or by using some javascript that injects the css in your page

Comment: I used javascript to add it in the page and here is the relevant piece of code f.setAttribute("href", "chrome://<appname>/chrome/skin/tagem.widget.css"); For appname should I use the name from the chrome.manifest? Thanks